# (ReactJS) Non-interactive elements should not be assigned mouse or keyboard event listeners

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am receiving this error and two warnings  :

> Non-interactive elements should not be assigned mouse or keyboard
>   event listeners.

and

> video and onVideo select are missing in props validation

```
import React from 'react';

const VideoListItem = ({ video, onVideoSelect }) => {
  const imageUrl = video.snippet.thumbnails.default.url;

  return (
    <li onClick={() => onVideoSelect(video)} className="list-group-item">
      <div className="video-list media">
        <div className="media-left">
          <img className="media-object" src={imageUrl} alt="Media" />
        </div>

        <div className="media-body">
          <div className="media-heading">{video.snippet.title}</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>
  );
};

export default VideoListItem;
```

Will someone please assist me in the proper way of correcting these issues.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

First warning means, that you should not have `onClick` event listener on `li` element, only on element like `<a>` or `<button>` element.

Second warning is about not using PropTypes package - you should validate props you are passing to your component - it says what the passed props should be - in your case `video` is an object, `onVideoSelect` is a function, right? You use the package https://www.npmjs.com/package/prop-types like this:

```
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'; // or PropTypes = require('prop-types');

const VideoListItem = ({ video, onVideoSelect }) => {...};

VideoListItem.propTypes = {
  video: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
  onVideoSelect: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
};
```

If you omit `isRequired`, you'll get warning about not having default value for props (assuming you are using airbnb linter config - it looks like it). You can fix it like this:

```
VideoListItem.defaultProps = {
  video: {},
  onVideoSelect: () => {},
}
```

Comment: Can you please explain the prop types a little more. I don't understand what I am supposed to do to get rid of the warning and why I am doing it.

Comment: I edited my original answer, take a look and let me know if you need more explanation. Good luck!

Comment: @DavidBrierton This is the correct answer. The only other things that should be added are the fact that you are getting the first "error" (more like a warning) from React, which is trying to get you to follow best practices, and the second "error", is only an "error" because your linter decides that it is. Use of PropTypes helps to ensure that the data you are providing as props are the correct data types (like you are not accidently supplying null when you should be supplying a function, etc)